# HTML beginner, about image size

Tags: html, image, size

I want to create a simple div header to start my website and i have two pics *logo.png* and *grey.jpg* as background to my div. My logo wants to have the same height as the header, but to be left and to have something like `10%` of the width.
The problem is that is that the logo doesnt seem to stay in size.It exceeds the height of the header if i put body size in auto.

```html
<html>  
  <head>
    <title>Museum page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Home Museum">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      body {
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right:10%;
        text-align:center;
      }
      div#header{
        height:10%;
        width:100%;
        background-image: url("images/grey.jpg"); text-align:center;}

      nav{background-color:#d8d8d8;}

      footer{background-color:white;clear:both;}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:15%;height:100%;">           
      <h1> Giorgos Angelousis life story </h1>
      AM:2969 <br>Exercise-1a<br><br>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <a href="#top">TOP </a>
    </footer>
  </body>   
</html>
```

I want the logo to be the same height as the div , head.

Comment: Try to add `div#header img{ height:100%; }`

Comment: @MoshFeu He already got that in his inline CSS... By the way i wouldn`t mix up external and inline-CSS

Comment: You are right.. I didn't see it. So the you need to set the `body` - `height:100%` or set the `#header` fix height (in `px` for example)

Comment: Yeah, give the header a fixed px-height (as MoschFeu said) and it will work. A %-height for a header does not make much sense anyway i think.

Comment: also i want the div header to stay the same if i dont put text in it , and not accomodate its content.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `width:15%` from     `<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:15%;height:100%;">`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/1h5n2get/) for you :)

HTML:

```
<div class="flex">
  <div>
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Smiley face" style="width:50px;height:100px;">         
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <h1> Giorgos Angelousis life story </h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      AM:2969 
    </div>
    <div>
      Exercise-1a
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.middle{
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **height:100%** from your `<img>` tag. So it will automatically get the height of **header** div. Here's sample snippet.

```html
<html>  
  <head>
    <title>Museum page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Home Museum">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      body {
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right:10%;
        text-align:center;
      }
      div#header{
        height:10%;
        width:100%;
        background-image: url("images/grey.jpg"); text-align:center;}

      nav{background-color:#d8d8d8;}

      footer{background-color:white;clear:both;}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <img src="test-img.jpg" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;width:15%;">           
      <h1> Giorgos Angelousis life story </h1>
      AM:2969 <br>Exercise-1a<br><br>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <a href="#top">TOP </a>
    </footer>
  </body>   
</html>
```